# Finding a set or Path in a Large Undirected Graph which is constructed from sets

Tags: math, graph-theory

Given three sets, ABC, each consisting of a series of nodes. For example, set A contains Nodes: a1, a2, a3; set B contains b1, b2; and set C contains c1, c2, c3, c4. Each node has a weight, for instance, a1 <-> a1Weight. For example:

a1: 1, Connected with b1, b2, c2...

a2: 2, Connected with b2, c2...

a3: 5, Connected with b2, d2...

b1...

Nodes from different sets have connections; for instance, a1 can be connected to b1 and c1. Connection is not weighted.

The question is HOW to select one node from each set, to ensure the total score of Selected Nodes is maximized while maintaining connections between the nodes.

like that:

Selected Nodes: [a3, b2, c2, d1, e1, f1]

Rest Part: [a1, a2, b1, b3, c1, d2, e2, f2, f3]

Ensure that in the selected nodes, EACH 2 nodes are connected & the total weights area maximum.

This question will have a large data set (more than 10 sets and each sets would have more than 500 nodes) in real scenarios. Multiple results with same & maximum score should be all found.

Comment: I think you should specify whether or not A, B, and C can have common elements. In other words, is | A U B U C | = |A| + |B| + |C| necessarily? Problems like this are generally addressed by iteratively finding improving sub-optimal solutions using the time allowed. Finding the absolute best solution might not be technically feasible in a reasonable time with current technology. Also, I think you should clarify what connections are necessary. As you've worded it, it sounds like there aren't any restrictions there.

Comment: yeah in the problem, | A U B U C | = |A| + |B| + |C| has to be like that. Thanks for the advice, we realize that maybe solving that problem was to work on the perorder steps to avoid the data set like that.

Comment: Please clarify your question.   What you mean by "maintaining connections"? Do you mean "remove nodes that do NOT increase the number of components in the graph"?  Or something else?

Comment: Please clarify your question.  What you mean by "ensure the total score is maximized". The total score of what? The  total score of the nodes selected to be removed? The total score of the nodes remaining?

Comment: Yeah the "The total score of the nodes selected to be removed".

Comment: Please [edit] your post to make the problem specification clear and self-contained.  Don't put clarifications in the comments -- revise your post, so it reads well and is clear for someone who encounters this for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The question is HOW to select one item from each set, to ensure the total score is maximized while maintaining connections between the nodes."

Your question is not entirely clear on what you mean by "maintaining connections".  I am going to assume that you mean "remove nodes that do NOT increase the number of components in the graph"

Your question is also not entirely clear on what you mean by "ensure the total score is maximized".  The total score of what?  The nodes selected to be removed?  The total score of the nodes remaining?

Anyway, this problem can be solved by finding the bridges in your graph, if any.

"In graph theory, a bridge, isthmus, cut-edge, or cut arc is an edge of a graph whose deletion increases the graph's number of connected components."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory)

Notice that this definition is concerned with the edges of a graph.  So you will need to first process your graph as follows:  Convert every edge to a node, and the nodes into edges.  Like this:

[image]

Now apply one of the algorithms described in the Wikipedia article to find the bridge "edges".

Finally, mark the nodes in the original graph that are represented by bridge edges. and select from the UN-marked nodes in each set, according to whatever total you are optimizing for.

Comment: Thanks! that's really a new idea. I do think it worth some time to try.